# How to find the dimension of the polar cone of a convex cone generated by some given vectors

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, convex-polytopes, convex-geometry, convex-optimization, cones

Suppose we have access to a generating set $\{v_1, ..., v_k\}\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ of the convex cone $C=cone(v_1, ..., v_k)$, where $cone(\cdot)$ is the conical hull (i.e. nonnegative span) of vectors in $(\cdot)$. Is there an easy way to find out the dimension of its polar cone $C^*:=\{\alpha\in\mathbb{R}^n:\alpha^Tx\geq0,\forall\ x\in C\}$?

I am wondering whether it is possible to specify this dimension from properties of the $n\times k$ matrix (such as rank, eigenvalues, etc.), whose columns are $v_1, ..., v_k$. Any help or suggestion is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Could you specify what you mean by the dimension of a cone? The dimension of its linear span?

Comment: It is the dimension of the smallest affine space containing the cone.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Well, as your cone contains $0$, the smallest affine space that contains the cone is actually the same as the linear span of the cone, right?

Comment: Yes. That is correct.

Comment: My very weak intuition says that it should be the codimension of the largest *linear* subset of your cone, or is that tautologous?

Comment: @Lubin Yes, you are very right on that. The largest linear subset you mension is called the **lineality space**. In fact, the specific thing I want to know from $\{v_1, ..., v_k\}$ is whether this space has dimension $\geq 1$ or not, which is a subproblem of what I posted.